# The irreducible character of $2.L_2(p)$ where p is a prime

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Hello
As I checked the atlas of finite simple groups if $p$ is a prime then according to the notations of the atlas of finite simple groups,  $2.L_2(p)$ has an irreducible character of degree $(p-1)/2$ or $(p+1)/2$.
Why this character exists and is it true for each prime number $p>3$?
Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I can tell you that $L_2(p)$ always has an irreducible character of degree $p$ for any prime $p$. Recall that $L_2(p)$ is simply $G/Z(G)$ where $G$ is $SL_2(p)$. The character of $L_2(p)$ of degree $p$ is then simply obtained from the Steinberg character of $SL_2(p)$. This is defined, for instance, in Digne and Michel's book "Representations of Finite Groups of Lie Type". Unfortunately I don't know enough about double covers to tell you why you get the character of degree 2p. However it should be a character covering the Steinberg character.

Comment: Thanks, Jay, for explaining that $L_2(p)$ is just $PSL_2(p)$. But what is $2.L_2(p)$ exactly?

Comment: @Alain: The notation ${\rm L}_n(q)$ for ${\rm PSL}(n,q)$ is often used by people working on finite simple groups, in the spirit that series of simple groups deserve simple (i.e. one-letter) names.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake in the question. In fact I want to ask that is it true that  the non-split extension of $L_2(p)$ by $Z_2$ has an irreducible  character of degree $(p-1)/2$ or $(p+1)/2$ in general. In fact in the atlas of finite group we see that $2.L_2(11)$ has an irreducible character of degree 6, or $2.L_2(13)$ has an irreducible character of degree 8.  

Comment: @Stefan: you mean that $2.L_2(P)$ is $SL_2(p)$? Oh boy...

Comment: yes, in fact this is the same, and I need the irreducible character degrees of $SL_2(p)$ or more generally $SL_2(q)$, could you introduce me a reference for it.

Comment: @BHZ: The question may be too elementary for MO (going back to Frobenius/Schur a century ago).   Character tables are developed in a few textbooks (including I guess James-Liebeck), but there is also an old expository paper of mine (if you can access it via JSTOR or in print): *Representations of SL(2,p)*, Amer. Math. Monthly 82 (1975), 21--39.  The ideas are pretty much the same over larger finite fields.

Comment: P.S. I emphasized how elementary the work of Frobenius/Schur was. But the end result is somewhat opaque. For a much more difficult but rewarding modern treatment, see the 2011 Springer book by Cedric Bonnafe *Representations of `$\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$`.* This points the way to Deligne-Lusztig character theory for groups of Lie type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so if I am not mistaken the non-split extension of $L_2(p)$ should simply be $SL_2(p)$. You are now asking whether $SL_2(p)$ has a character of degree $(p-1)/2$ or $(p+1)2$ when $p \neq 2$. Indeed this is true. The generic character table of $SL_2(q)$ is given in Table 5.4 of Bonnafe's book "Representations of $SL_2(q)$". We see from this table that the degrees of the irreducible characters of $SL_2(p)$ are contained in the list

$$1,p,\frac{p+1}{2},\frac{p-1}{2},p+1,p-1$$

There is only one character of degree 1, the trivial character, and one character of degree $p$, the Steinberg character. There are then two characters of degree $\frac{p+1}{2}$ and two characters of degree $\frac{p-1}{2}$. These occur as irreducible constituents of the restriction of an irreducible Deligne-Lusztig character of $GL_2(p)$. When $p=2$ then one obtains the character table of $SL_2(p)$ simply by restricting the characters of $GL_2(p)$.

You may also find this useful by Mark Reeder.

https://www2.bc.edu/~reederma/SL(2,q).pdf

Comment: Sorry, I was in the process of changing an answer to the OP's original question before he changed it. The above now explains why $SL_2(p)$ has irreducible characters of degree $\frac{p-1}{2}$ and $\frac{p+1}{2}$.